# Delphi: determine actual type of a generic?

Tags: delphi, generics

Is there any way to determine the type of a variable passed as an argument to a method? Consider the class:

```
TSomeClass = class
  procedure AddToList<T: TDataType; U: TListClass<T>>(Element: T; List: U);
end;
```

with the method implementation

```
procedure TSomeClass.AddToList<T, U>(Element: T; List: U);
begin
  if Element is TInt then
    List.AddElement(TInt.Create(XXX))
  else if Element is TString then
    List.AddElement(TString.Create(YYY));
end;
```

where TInt.Create() and TString.Create() have different sets of arguments, yet, they both inherit from TDataType.

Now, I know the `is`-operator can't be used like this, but is there a legal alternative that does what I'm asking here?

Comment: If the first thing you do in your generic code is write type-specific code for each possible generic value, then you're not writing generic code anymore. This is not the place to use generics.

Comment: Thanks for the input Rob. When I'm posting questions at SO (and other places), I usually come up with dumbed-down versions of my real code. Extracting the essence of the problem is, in my experience, more useful than presenting real-world code - code which usually is quite more complex. So please consider the above code an illustration of a larger problem. Btw: I'd love to read about an alternative to the above code. Please check out my follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761487/delphi-generics-and-is-operator-problem. I'm looking forward to any input on that post! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not being able to use the **is** operator here is a known issue, but there's a pretty simple workaround.

```
  if TObject(Element) is TInt then
    List.AddElement(TInt.Create(XXX))
```

Also, since the type of a generic is part of the class and is known at compile-time, you might be better off restructuring your code.  Make two different generic classes, one of which accepts a TInt as its `<T>` parameter, and the other of which accepts a TString.  Put the type-specific functionality into them at that level, and have them descend from a common ancestor for shared functionality.

Comment: Thanks Mason! However, I'm getting an "E2089 invalid typecast" error. Do you know why? And I might've been unclear in my last post, but TInt and TString both descend from TDataType, but they differ at TInt and TString level (in particular their constructors). That's what you meant, right? Anyway - the constraint is put as "near" TInt and TString as possible to ensure optimal functionality.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?  I don't have your code to test on, but I wrote up a simple test and casting to TObject works fine for me...

Comment: In my original post, I was working with a more complex design, but gave the example as presented above, because it captures the essential problem I'm having. So, when asked for the entire source, I had to code it from "scratch". It looks a little different, but I'm still having the typecast-issue. Should I post it as a separate question, or as an answer to your post?

Comment: It would probably be better to post it as a separate question.  But bear in mind what Rob Kennedy wrote in his comment above.  He's got a good point.

Comment: Thanks Mason. I had to run yesterday, so that's the reason for the delay... I've commented Rob's comment (together with the link to the new post). I'm sure Rob has a point, and I would love to get some feedback on the matter. When do you believe it makes sense to use generics? The TInt and TStr examples are only two specific data types. Imagine you have 15-20 others as well... I believe that constitutes a sensible use of generics. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

This question I asked some time ago

[Conditional behaviour based on concrete type for generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805931/conditional-behaviour-based-on-concrete-type-for-generic-class)

might be of interest, especially if you want to use not only `TObject` descendants but also primitive types in your conditionals.

Comment: +1 You saved my day as I needed the linked answer to enable generic conversion functions for enumerated types.