# How to cast generic T to a TObject?

Tags: delphi, generics

I have a method that needs to return an object. Of course, it only makes sense if the `T` ***is*** an object:

```
function TGrobber<T>.Swipe: TObject;
var
   current: T;
begin
    {
       If generic T is not an object, then there's nothing we can return
       But we'll do the caller a favor and not crash horribly.
    }
    if PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T))^.Kind <> tkClass then
    begin
       Result := nil;
       Exit;
    end;

    //We *are* an object, return the object that we are.
    current := Self.SwipeT;

    Result := TObject(current); <--E2089 invalid class typecast
end;
```

If `T` is not an object (e.g. an `Integer`, `String`, or `OleVariant`), then it will return `nil`, and not crash horribly.

If we are an object (e.g. `TCustomer`, `TPatron`, `TSalesOrder`, `TShape`), then we can return the object just fine.

I didn't want to confuse the issue; but if you look at `IEnumerable`, you'll see what is actually going on.

### Bonus Reading

- [Delphi: determine actual type of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755938/delphi-determine-actual-type-of-a-generic)
- [Conditional behaviour based on concrete type for generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805931/conditional-behaviour-based-on-concrete-type-for-generic-class)

## Answer

I'll let TLama copy/paste the answer to get his credit:

```
function TGrobber<T>.Swipe: TObject;
var
   current: T;
   v: TValue;
begin
    current := Self.SwipeT;
    v := TValue.From<T>(current);
    {
       If generic T is not an object, then there's nothing we can return
       But we'll do the caller a favor and not crash horribly.
    }
    if not v.IsObject then
    begin
       Result := nil;
       Exit;
    end;

    Result := v.AsObject;
end;
```

Comment: What would the compiler turn that statement into if T is, say, `byte`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I tested the concept. The code `Result := TObject(Byte(7));` compiles and runs. Presumably it is an access violation in waiting. Fortunately, because of my pre-condition, i would never cast a `Byte` to a `TObject`.

Comment: Could be `TValue.From<T>(current).AsObject` ?

Comment: @TLama Wow, that `TValue` helper record solves everything. Copy/paste the answer i added to the question for your reputation reward.

Comment: If possible I would avoid boxing and unboxing a TValue.

Comment: I'd like to know why you aren't constraining? I'd also avoid TValue no matter what.

Comment: @StefanGlienke and DavidHeffernan, can you please briefly ellaborate on why avoiding TValue boxing/unboxing? Or give a link where it is explained? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @Guillem TValue is heavyweight and not designed for this task. Either constrain at compile time or use something like: `Result := PObject(@current)^`

Comment: @David, ok, thanks for the explanation. I use `TValue` in a class that uses `RTTI` to autocreate *SOAP requests* with the developer only having to specify the parameters (i.e. no creation and assignation of object instances at all). It is quite useful for complicated SOAP requests with several levels, and while it works flawlessly I was now worried it would have some caveat I did not know about.

Comment: @Guillem TValue has its place, which is typically as a conduit for RTTI method arguments

Comment: `IEnumerable` and the corresponding `IEnumerator` are just an accident by Emba, looking too much at .net and getting confused by .net `System.Object` and translated it to delphi `TObject`. But in .net **every type** inherits from `System.Object` (even a `System.String`) and in delphi it is different. Maybe someone will tell them someday

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The reason i'm not constraining is because `IEnumerable<T>` allows my list to contain **anything**. And i **want** it to be able to contain strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two main options. If the generic type must be a class type, and this is know at compile time, you should apply a constraint to the type:

```
type
  TGrobber<T: class> = class
    ....
  end;
```

Or if the type must derive from a specific class then that constraint can be specifies like so:

```
type
  TGrobber<T: TMyObject> = class
    ....
  end;
```

Once the constraint is applied then direct assignment is all you need.

```
Result := current;
```

This becomes possible because the compiler enforces the constraint on your generic type. And so knows that the assignment is valid for all possible instantiations.

I would comment that it seems odd for a generic class to have a function returning `TObject`. Why doesn't your function return `T`?

If you cannot constrain then a simple pointer type cast is the cleanest approach:

```
Result := PObject(@current)^;
```

Obviously you need to check that `T` is a class type, code for which you have already demonstrated mastery.

For what it is worth, since Delphi XE7 it is simpler to check the kind of a type using `System.GetTypeKind`:

```
if GetTypeKind(T) = tkClass then
  Result := PObject(@current)^
else
  Result := nil;
```

Comment: `TValue` does the same thing your code (cast a Pointer to a TObject to defeat typing). Although to does calculate some additional things during `From<T>`. On the other hand, there is the virtue of using the canonical `TValue` typing helper record to interrogate and manipulate generic types at runtime.

Comment: @IanBoyd I don't believe that is what `TValue` is intended for. However, you are clearly free to do it that way if you prefer. Personally I would do it the way I wrote above, but it's not something to get too hot under the collar about either way.

Comment: Also, it turns out `GetTypeKind` doesn't exist in my version of Delphi. Here we go again.

Comment: Yes, it is new in XE7 it seems. I guess your code wins out for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done via TValue but it is not the correct way to do it. I belive it is much better to let the compiler verify that it is a TObject (or descendant).

```
unit GrobberU;

interface

type
  TGrobber<T : Class> = class
  public
    function Swipe: TObject;
  end;

implementation

{ TGrobber<T> }

function TGrobber<T>.Swipe: TObject;
begin
  Result := T;
end;

end.
```

Then you can test it :

```
procedure TForm37.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Grobber1 : TGrobber<TEdit>;
  Grobber2 : TGrobber<Integer>; <-- Does not compile    
begin
end;
```

[image]

Comment: `Result := T` does not compile because `T` is a type and not an instance. Also, there's no need for a screenshot to show a compiler error. Compiler errors are text. They can simply be pasted verbatim as text.

Comment: You are right @DavidHeffernan the return value of Swipe ahould ofcause be Result := SwipeT. But it does compile though

Comment: No, it does not compile. *[dcc32 Error] E2010 Incompatible types: 'TObject' and 'T'*

Comment: Then let me be more precise: In Delphi Xe it does

Comment: Then it's a compiler bug. I don't understand why you persist with this.

Comment: @Jens You must return a value of type T and not T itself, because T is just the type. If you rent a car you expect to get a real car and not some sheet of papers where you can read how to create a car ;o)

Comment: In my case, `TGrobber` can contain any type, including non-classes.