# Detect concrete type of generic class at compile type

Tags: delphi, generics

Followup on this question: [Conditional behaviour based on concrete type for generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805931/conditional-behaviour-based-on-concrete-type-for-generic-class)

I know you can detect the type of a generic variable using RTTI. However I would like to go one step further.  Is there a way to detect the type at compile time.

I have the following code:

```
function TBPlusTree<K, V>.TLeaf.AddKey(const Key: K; const Value: V): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i:= 0;
  while i < fCount do begin
    if Key = fKeys[i] then exit(false); // Key already exists
    //Todo: replace with binary search
    if Key < fKeys[i] then begin
      // Make space for the key
      Move(fKeys[i], fKeys[i+1], (fCount - i) * SizeOf(TKey));
      // If the key is a String or DynArray zero out the pointer
      if (SizeOf(K) = SizeOf(NativeInt)) then NativeInt((@fKeys[i])^):= 0;
      // If the value is a String or DynArray zero out the pointer
      Move(fValues[i], fValues[i+1], (fCount - i) * SizeOf(V));
      if (SizeOf(V) = SizeOf(NativeInt)) then NativeInt((@fValues[i])^):= 0;
      break;
    end;
    Inc(i);
  end; { while }
  Inc(fCount);
  //ClearKey(fKeys[i]);
  fKeys[i]:= Key;
  // if ValueType = tkUString then UniqueString(PString(@fValues[i])^);
  fValues[i]:= Value;
  Result:= true;
end;
```

If the tree hold a string as its K or V type then the pointer needs to be zeroed. 
The `move` defeats the COW mechanism and the 2 strings will have the new value.

The nice thing about the above `if then` is that the compiler eliminates the test.

```
BPlusTrees.pas.454: if (SizeOf(K) = SizeOf(NativeInt)) then NativeInt((@fKeys[i])^):= 0;
0056BBC4 8B4610           mov eax,[esi+$10]  //Test is eliminated by compiler.
0056BBC7 8D0498           lea eax,[eax+ebx*4]
0056BBCA 33D2             xor edx,edx
0056BBCC 8910             mov [eax],edx
```

Because the SizeOf can be resolved at compile time the compiler can see that the test always resolves to `true` (or false) and will eliminate it.

**However**
The above code needs to only run for reference counted types i.e.: interfaces, strings and dynarrays.
Right now it also runs for integers, objects etc.

The problem with `TypeInfo` is that it generates checking code which takes more time than the actual code I'm trying to avoid.

```
BPlusTrees.pas.454: if (SizeOf(K) = SizeOf(NativeInt)) and
          (PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(K))^.Kind <> tkInteger) 
          then NativeInt((@fKeys[i])^):= 0;
0056BBC4 A19C104000       mov eax,[$0040109c]
0056BBC9 803801           cmp byte ptr [eax],$01
0056BBCC 740A             jz $0056bbd8
0056BBCE 8B4610           mov eax,[esi+$10]
0056BBD1 8D0498           lea eax,[eax+ebx*4]
0056BBD4 33D2             xor edx,edx
0056BBD6 8910             mov [eax],edx
```

**Is there a way to narrow down the above test so that the test expression can still be resolved at compile time so that it compiles to the same code as above but excludes more types?**

I've had a look at the intrinsic routines, but I see nothing there that can help me: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines

Comment: Initialize almost does the job, it only gets called for managed types, but.... Initialize does sooo much work it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to distinguish, at compile time, unconstrained generic types. There is no operator that is evaluated at compile time that can tell a managed type from an unmanaged type.

**Update**

Since XE7, there is a new intrinsic `IsManagedType` that is designed to meet your needs. This intrinsic is, as yet, undocumented. Perhaps the best reference is here: http://delphisorcery.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/new-language-feature-in-xe7.html?m=1

Comment: Bummer, the issue is, the compiler knows what K and V are, so why does it not let me access that info at compile time. A simple `if K is string` should do the job.

Comment: Dunno. The designers didn't include any traits mechanisms beyond sizeof.

Comment: In XE7 we have the new intrinsic IsManagedType, would that not do the job?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I presume this answer predates XE7.

Answer (score 0):

From XE7 onwards the (undocumented) intrinsic function `IsManagedType` can be used.

Like so:

```
if IsManagedType(K) then ...
```

The *is* a way to do this pre-XE7, by using an (also undocumented) side effect of the `TypeInfo` intrinsic function.
If you compare one TypeInfo against another TypeInfo the result will be evaluated at compile time.

Thus:

```
if TypeInfo(K) = TypeInfo(UnicodeString) then .... //resolves at compile type
if (PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(K))^.Kind <> tkUString) //produces lots of code.
```

so a test to compare against all expected managed types will do the job.
Obviously if a record is used that itself contains a managed type then TypeInfo will not help, but `IsManagedType` will.