# Java type specific behaviour with generics

Tags: java, design-patterns, switch-statement

The problem is as follows:

There are the entities Box, Boxvalue, Boxstrategy and then as example "IntegerBoxStrategy".
The concept is quite simple, I'd like to put different kind of types in this box. Sometimes there will be an Integer inside this Box, sometimes a String. I want to be able to do specific conversion between these types (so type specific behaviour -> hence my strategy approach. Every type will require a specific strategy to convert) and these types can be specified with an ENUM.

So after googling a lot (though I'm quite sure this question might be marked as duplicate and say that I haven't googled enough ;) ) i'm trying this approach:
https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue123.html

Concise summary of this approach: they use a strategy to implement a taxstrategy for taxpayers. UML will be more easy to understand: 
[image: UML class diagram for first link]
Though in my case, I'd only have one "Taxpayer", aka the BoxType.

fyi: this question is really similar : [Conditional behaviour based on concrete type for generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805931/conditional-behaviour-based-on-concrete-type-for-generic-class) though -> i want to be able to switch between my BoxValues, and convert "true" into "1". But I think that the approach of the answer might be helpful, Run time type identification. Which in my case would be used to match strategies with their according "supported types".

The problem with the first link is that in every specific strategy implementation, I'm going to have a huge switch. (sample code later on)

My question is not something like "solve this for me please" but more like point me in the general direction. If a simple example could be given how this could be done when you don't have to update every specific strategy implementation when you support a new "boxvaluetype", I'd be really happy. If posssible, I'd like the cleanest design implementation or approach according to the GRASP principles.

```
 public interface typeStrategy {
    boolean canChangeToType(Object myvalue,ValueType type);
    boolean correctType(Object myvalue);
}

class BoolTypeStrategy implements typeStrategy{

    @Override
    public boolean canChangeToType(Object myvalue, ValueType type) {
        if (correctType(myvalue))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("your initial value should be a boolean!");
        switch (type){
            case INT:
                return true;
            case STRING:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean correctType(Object myvalue) {
        if (!(myvalue instanceof Boolean))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the example, this ValueType is my Enum.

```
public class BoxValue<T> {
    private T value;
    private typeStrategy mystrategy;


    public BoxValue(T value, typeStrategy strategy) {
        this.value = value;
        this.mystrategy = strategy;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean canChangeToType(ValueType type){
        return mystrategy.canChangeToType(value, type);
    }
}
```

As you can see, huge switches solve the problem.. So what design patterns, what suggestions are recommended to solve this problem? (fyi: I'd like to resolve this in Java 8, as i am aware that there are these strange "var" types in Java10+)

Comment: Please don't link to external resources without summarizing what's being said there. If the target page goes permanently offline the link will be useless and the question will lack important informations.

Comment: Got it! I'll update it in a second, thank you for your comment!

Comment: Edited, if it's still not good enough then i'll write / copy paste parts of the problem / solution.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have the type itself include the other types it can convert itself to. Conversion is something that is done to the type (or rather, between two types), so I'd see that as a concern for an outside service class.

Comment: @daniu , Thank you for your response. Aren't you either 1. creating crazy amount of methods then? 2. Or solving this with method overloading or 3. switch inside switch statements? That is ofcourse all inside of your service class